# I want to use 60 kinds of original markers (.patt) in AR.js

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm combining A-frame and AR.js,
An error will occur if 51 or more .patt files are registered.
If there are 50 .patt files, it works fine.

error message：
`loadMarker(): Error loading pattern file /marker_50.`

*The last number changes with each load.

- There is no problem with the server or .patt files.
- I searched github to see if there was a limit to the number of .patt files, but I couldn't find it.

I think it's bad to call them all at once, but are there any workarounds or "aframe-ar.js" settings?

.patt registration is done like this.

`<a-marker type="pattern" url="marker/pattern-49.patt" id="m49" registerevents></a-marker>`

`<a-marker type="pattern" url="marker/pattern-50.patt" id="m50" registerevents></a-marker>`

`<a-marker type="pattern" url="marker/pattern-51.patt" id="m51" registerevents></a-marker>`

Comment: Saw Jerome Etienne (ar.js OG creator) claiming that he's not aware of any hard coded limits. The idea sounds cool, I'll try reproducing it.

Comment: You can load maximum 50 Patt files as stated in this Define: https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/blob/5bf0b671ff16ead527b9b892e6aeb1a2771f97be/include/AR/arConfig.h#L82 You can of course change this number but you need to rebuild the libs by you.